Add dynamic value in the header
i use spring cloud gateway mvc.
We can add header value with addRequestHeader
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> bookServiceRoute() {
        return route("bookRoute")
                .route(RequestPredicates.path("/bff/**"), http("http://localhost:8001"))
                .before(rewritePath("/crm/bff/(?<segment>.*)", "/acme/crm/${segment}"))
                .before(addRequestHeader("X-User-Key", "test"))
                .build();
    }

that work fine.
Now i seach to take a value in the session and put it header.
I tried to add a line like
.before(addRequestHeaderDynamicValue())

but this method  then i created is only called one time when program start
so how to add dynamic content to route?
public class UserHeaderFilter {


    @Autowired
    UserHelper helper;

    public Function<ServerRequest, ServerRequest> addRequestHeaderDynamicValue() {
        return request -> {
            String email = helper.userProfile.getEmail();
            Consumer<HttpHeaders> headers = httpHeaders -> {
            ...
            };
            ServerRequest.from(request).headers(headers).build();
            return request;
        };
    }
}


Filters run every request, so your custom filter needs to calculate a dynamic value

if i replace .before by .filter, it don't work, filter don't access my UserHeaderFilter class method

Server request from returns a new request which you ignore and return the old one
